# OSGi bundle (State - Active) (Spring - Started)

Tags: spring, osgi, karaf

When I start karaf client and type list command i can see OSGi bundles statistic.
For each OSGi bundle there is several values, and 'Spring' among them.
I need programmatically get Spring state from all OSGi bundles where there is Spring context.
I'm tying to write an util method that should 'wait for all Spring contexts from all bundles to be up and running'
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to program this yourself then you can do the same as the karaf bundle service in the [SpringStateService](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/karaf-3.0.x/bundle/springstate/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/state/spring/internal/SpringStateService.java).

You can also simply leverage the [BundleStateService](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/karaf-3.0.x/bundle/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/core/BundleStateService.java). You need to watch for all such services and use the one that returns "Spring DM" in getName().

Comment: I still have problem with detecting 'started' state because for some bundles I receive only 'ACTIVE' (end) event, but there was no correspondent 'UNKNOWN' (start) event for it. As thus my service gives me 'started' event several times.